# ggplot: show legend of dashed line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got the following problem.

I am using ggplot and in legend I want to show dashed lines.

Here is my code:

```
  N=function(z)(0.08-0.06*((1-exp(-z/1.5))/(z/1.5))-0.3*((1-exp(-z/
                                       1.5))/(z/1.5)-exp(-(z/1.5)))+
                0.6*((1-exp(-z/0.5))/(z/0.5)-exp(-(z/0.5))))
    M=function(z)(0.2-0.06*((1-exp(-z/1.5))/(z/1.5))-0.3*((1-exp(-z/
                                                                    1.5))/(z/1.5)-exp(-(z/1.5)))+
                    0.6*((1-exp(-z/0.5))/(z/0.5)-exp(-(z/0.5))))
    
    ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-0.2, 25)), aes(x = x)) +
  geom_hline(aes(colour="navajowhite3", yintercept = 0.08, colour = "break"), size = 0.9, 
              show.legend = TRUE)+
  geom_path(aes(linetype=2,colour="lightskyblue3"), stat="function", fun=N, size = 0.9,linetype=2)+
  geom_path(aes(colour="grey39"), stat="function", fun=M, size = 0.9)+
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Georgia"))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  labs(y ="interest rate (%)", x = "Maturity (year)")+ theme_light() +
  scale_colour_identity("Shapes:", guide="legend", 
                        labels = c(expression(beta[0]),  "new"), 
                        breaks = c("navajowhite3",  "grey39"))+
  scale_linetype_identity( guide="legend", 
                        labels = c("old"), 
                        breaks = c(2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12), legend.title=element_text(size=12))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14))+
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14))+theme(plot.caption=element_text(size=14))
```

And I got this:

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be one way to achieve what you want?

ggplot generally prefers data in 'long' format; all the work in preparing the data has been carried out in the dataframe which is then passed to the ggplot function for visualisation.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

  data.frame(year = seq(-0.2, 25, length.out = 100)) %>% 
  mutate( old = N(year),
          new = M(year),
          beta = 0.08) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, value))+
    geom_line(aes(group = name, colour = name, linetype = name), size = 1)+
    scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("beta", "new", "old"),
                        labels = c(expression(beta[0]),  "new", "old"),
                        values = c("navajowhite3", "grey39", "lightskyblue3"))+
    scale_linetype_manual(breaks = c("beta", "new", "old"),
                          labels = c(expression(beta[0]),  "new", "old"),
                          values = c(1, 1, 2))+
    labs(x = "Maturity [year]",
         y = "Interest rate [%]",
         colour = "Shapes",
         linetype = "Shapes")+
    theme_bw()
```

**functions**

```r
N=function(z)(0.08-0.06*((1-exp(-z/1.5))/(z/1.5))-0.3*((1-exp(-z/
                                                                1.5))/(z/1.5)-exp(-(z/1.5)))+
                0.6*((1-exp(-z/0.5))/(z/0.5)-exp(-(z/0.5))))
M=function(z)(0.2-0.06*((1-exp(-z/1.5))/(z/1.5))-0.3*((1-exp(-z/
                                                               1.5))/(z/1.5)-exp(-(z/1.5)))+
                0.6*((1-exp(-z/0.5))/(z/0.5)-exp(-(z/0.5))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>